# How to download a file using RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl

I want to download a file but I have to send variables using POST to be able to do this. Right now I am using a `postForm` function to send the variables, but I don't know how to download the file.

`postForm` return something like this:

```
doc <- postForm("http://gpwinfostrefa.pl/GPWIS2/pl/quotes/archive/3", 
                dateFrom="2014-05-10", dateTo = "2014-06-10", 
                instrumentType = "10", isin="PLOPTTC00011", style="post",
                .opts=curlOptions(encoding="UTF-8", http.version=HTTP_VERSION_1_0))

> doc
[1] d0 cf 11 e0 a1 b1 1a e1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ...

attr(,"Content-Type")       charset 
"application/csv"           "UTF-8"

> str(doc)
atomic [1:10752] d0 cf 11 e0 ...
- attr(*, "Content-Type")= Named chr [1:2] "application/csv" "UTF-8"
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "" "charset"
```

but I don't know if I can do something with this. Is it possible (maybe using other function) to download a file simultaneously sending variables.

(PS. The file is an Excel file even though the Content-Type states that it is a csv)

Comment: Have you tried writing the returned value to a file? `cat(x, file="whatever")`?

Comment: So, I tried write the value to a file, but it didn't work. The file is just a text file `0 cf 11 e0 a1 b1 ...` (looks like wrote in hexadecimal) and I need an excel file :/. Maybe there is a way to convert this variable into a excel but I don't know how.

Comment: Give us the code you used to do the POST.

Comment: `doc <- postForm("http://gpwinfostrefa.pl/GPWIS2/pl/quotes/archive/3", dateFrom="2014-05-10", dateTo = "2014-06-10", instrumentType = "10", isin="PLOPTTC00011", style="post",
                .opts=curlOptions(encoding="UTF-8", http.version=HTTP_VERSION_1_0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as a binary vector to a file:

```
 > writeBin(as.vector(doc),"doc.xls")
```

I can then open that file with Libre Office.

Its so much easier to answer when you give the whole question!